# Cloud Firestore Read Operation 10 Times Higher in Billing

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

One of my App uses Firebase Firestore and has almost never exceed the daily free quota of 50k read operations. However last month I was charged for a few millions Firestore read operations.

Wanting to find out what was the problem, I checked my console (Usage and Billing) and confirmed that my everyday usage was under the 50k daily free quota during the whole billed month. Then I checked my usage today, in Firebase Console (Usage and Billing) it showed I have 45k read operations, but in my Google Cloud Platform (Quota), it showed 0.45m read operations, which was 10 times higher.

[image: Firebase Console -- Usage and Billing]
[image: Google Cloud Platform -- Quota]

Anyone faced this problem before? What could've gone wrong?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (it was also 10 times the amount!), and I am pretty sure for me it must be because reads to do backups are not counted on the firebase usage page, but are billed.  For a large database backups can be quite a problem.

It turns out there is a message here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import?authuser=1

It says:
"Caution: Exporting data from Cloud Firestore will incur one read operation per document exported. However, these reads will not appear in the usage section of the console. Make sure you understand this before setting up recurring exports to avoid an unexpected bill."

Hope this saves someone a bit of time!